# Monit catch run-away process

Tags: linux, monit

There are examples for how to make [Monit](http://mmonit.com/) detect a service going amok and use too much RAM. But what if the service forks a program and the child takes too much RAM?

Or put another way, how can I make [Monit](http://mmonit.com/) detect and act on any random process which is spawned and starts eating all the RAM.  Before the evil OOM starts killing processes left and right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excerpt from `man monit`

> **TOTALMEMORY** is the memory usage of the process and its child processes in either percent or as an amount (Byte, kB, MB, GB).

Comment: Well, that only seems to work when you have specified a specific process or service. Not just any random process popping into existence.